# Upload image to many different locations

Tags: laravel

I am creating an e-commerce platform that will be the central base for several sites that will take data from one database and the management of all sites will be from one place.
When a product category is created, I have the option to choose which store it will belong to (pivot db table).

When I create a new product and select a category and then select product images, those images need to be uploaded to the servers of the selected stores selected in the product category.

Example:
The central base and platform is at: [www.myadmin.com](http://www.myadmin.com)
I create a product category: Cars and choose that it is visible in 3 stores "**www.my-bmw.com**", "**www.my-audi.com**" and "**www.my-ford.com**"

After that, I create a new product "Rear glass" which belongs to the category "Cars". I select the image of the product "product.png" and when I save the product this image should be uploaded to the locations of the selected stores "**[www.my-bmw.com/images/product.png**"](http://www.my-bmw.com/images/product.png**%22), "**[www.my-audi.com/images/product.png**"](http://www.my-audi.com/images/product.png**%22) and "**[www.my-ford.com/images/product.png**"](http://www.my-ford.com/images/product.png**%22)

When creating a product, how can I check which stores are selected and add a new upload to a specific storage for each one?
My idea was to add an ftp upload path to each store and when creating a product to check which stores are selected and to upload to multiple destinations through foreach.

My code for uploading on base server is

```
private function _uploadProductImage(Request $request, $product_id, $showOnlyFilename = false)
    {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $name = pathinfo($image->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = config('ecommerce.product_upload_dir').'/'.Str::slug($product_id, '-');

        $image_upload_path = $path.'/'.$name.'.'.$extension;

        if(!$showOnlyFilename) {

            if($this->_imageExistOnStorage($image_upload_path)) {
                $this->_renameMainProductImageOnStorage($request, $product_id);
            }

            $this->ecommercePublicDisk()->put($image_upload_path, file_get_contents($image));
        }

        return  $image_upload_path;
    }
```

And disck

```
public function ecommercePublicDisk()
    {
        $disk = Storage::build([
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('/')
        ]);

        return $disk;
    }
```

Comment: I would probably utilize laravel queued jobs. When you save the image, dispatch a job which will in turn run the logic of checking which store needs the image and that way you can upload the image  to relevant stores

Comment: Are all websites on one virtual servers/ec2 instance and separated by vhost/server block? or all separate virtual servers/ec2 instance?

Comment: If in one server, are images separated by folders per website?

Comment: currently all websites is in local on different port and folder

Answer (score -1):

Just a thought but why would you need more than one copy of the image?

Why don't you same it on one place - say in s3 (I say with my AWS hat on)
Then in your database you have a table that has a record of the file and where it is in s3.

You can then link that `document` record with a `brand` in a `brand_document` joining (or pivot) many-to-many table.

Comment: This probably should have been posted as a comment instead of an answer. I do agree that duplication of the image seems completely unnecessary, but it's also possible that's just the business requirements.

Comment: I need different location storage for SEO puproses and image rankings

Comment: Quite @TimLewis - is there any meta doc on what should be what? 

It seems like they are interchangeable sometimes so a guide would help this padawan learner.

Comment: The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) pages may shed some light on what should be a comment vs what should be an answer, but my 2¢: if you're asking a question, or making a suggestion, then it should probably be a comment. Ultimately they are somewhat interchangeable, and if the person asking the question deems it acceptable as an answer, then my opinion is irrelevant, so use your best judgement 

Comment: That makes sense @TimLewis Thanks for the links and the tips. :)